# How to pause in the middle of a function (delay return) and continue on event

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to stop in the middle of a function, and wait for a certain event before continuing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it can be done. Once you begin execution of a function it will continue until the termination of the function. I believe what you might want to try is create two functions with a callback to the second function that is registered with the event you're listening for. However, it's tough to know that for sure since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: It was very hard for me to not write misleading code, but you understood me correctly. And thank you for the answer. I implemented it already.

Comment: to me this seems like the biggest flaw in javascript.  If functions could pause, we could just perform async IO calls without blocking and not get into callback hell.

Comment: @light24bulbs Regardless of language, if you ever find yourself thinking "I wish I could pause this function" what you are really saying is that you want two functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the second half of your code in an anonymous function and attach it as an event handler:

```
function myFunction() {
    firstHalfOfMyFunction();
    eventEmitter.on('someEvent', function () {
        secondHalfOfMyFunction();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/) which I use in my [Common Node](https://github.com/olegp/common-node/) library.

Comment: Seems like the perfect response for me. Trying node-fibers right now.